# Compare 2 dates of different flows in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to compare and calculate the elapsed time between 2 dates from diferent flows.

Supose you recieve every minute a json with a timestamp and you  want to calculate the difference between the actual csv and the previous one.

What I have done is:
With a EvaluateJsonPath get the timestamp
[image]

And after that, with an UpdateAttribute trying to store the timestamp and evaluate against the other one
[image]

[image]

I dont know why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of:

PutDistributedMapCache and FetchDistributedMapCache

Comment: nver used that feature, but i did use the cache (is local cache)

Comment: But how can I implement it, becasue if I use PutDistributedMapCache, because i want to store the date of the previous quequed file and sum to the actual one. Dont know how to do it with your solution. Could you put an example?